# No puedo centrar texto con Bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap, web

Me gustaría saber porqué Bootstrap no me centra el texto en el medio de la página. Les dejo el código y una imagen adjunta de la página.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <h1 class="text-center">Fuji Bodyboards </h1>.
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: al div que tienes con **col-xs-12** dejalo como **col-sm-12** y agregale la clase **d-flex justify-content-center** esa es una propiedad de Bootstrap este es el [LINK](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/), puedes buscarla y no es necesario ponerle la clase al **h1**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

para este caso puedes ocupar flex que viene con bootstrap, el único cambio que le haría a tu código sería el siguiente:

```
    <div class="container-fluid"> 
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <h1 class="text-center">Fuji Bodyboards </h1>.
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Modifiqué el **col-xs-12** que tienes por **col-sm-12** y le agregué la clase **d-flex justify-content-center** que es para centrar el texto, en realidad lo que hace no es centrar el texto, centra el elemento *h1* que tienes dentro del div.

Si quieres ver más ejemplos de la propiedad flex puedes ver este link ->[link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/)

Saludos